# Assertion failed: (!"unknown EAI * error code"), function u getaddrinfo translate error, file src/unix /getaddrinfo.c, line 90

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, knex.js

I'm encountering an assertion failed error in my Node.js application and I'm struggling to understand the cause and find a solution. The error message I'm getting is:

```
Assertion failed: (!"unknown EAI * error code"), 
function u getaddrinfo translate error,
file src/unix/getaddrinfo.c, line 90.
```

This error occurs when I'm trying to make a network call or establish a connection using the `getaddrinfo` function. I have tried searching for information on this specific error, but I couldn't find any relevant results.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar error before? What could be causing it, and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

I have encountered an assertion failed error in my Node.js application, specifically when using the `getaddrinfo` function. Here are the steps I have taken and my expectations:

Verified the input: I have double-checked the input parameters provided to the `getaddrinfo` function to ensure they are correct. I have also tried different input values to rule out any specific input-related issues.

Researched the error message: I have searched extensively for information on the specific error message, "unknown EAI * error code." However, I couldn't find any relevant results or specific explanations for this error.

Checked the Node.js version: I have confirmed that I am using the latest stable version of Node.js. Additionally, I have tried downgrading to a previous version to check if the issue persists, but it did not resolve the error.

Reviewed the relevant code: I have thoroughly reviewed the code that calls the `getaddrinfo` function and the surrounding logic. However, I couldn't identify any obvious issues that could lead to this error.

My Expectation: I was expecting the `getaddrinfo` function to successfully translate the provided address into the corresponding network address structure without encountering any assertion errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.